# Single declaration of connection string in form application

Tags: c#, winforms

In windows forms application there is no web.config. So how can i declare the single connection string? And how can I call it in another pages?

In App.config page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="CONSTRING" connectionString="Data Source=SQL-PC;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=True"/>
        </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

In Form I call this connectin string.

```
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using System.Configuration;

namespace Sample {
    public partial class Sample: Form
    {
        public string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Now there is error shows. `ConfigurationManager` does not exist in this current context. How can I solve it?

Comment: what do you mean by 'asp.net form application'. Do you mean an asp.net web form? or do you mean a .net windows form?

Comment: .net windows form. @steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager` class resides in `System.Configuration` assembly. And to make your code work you need to add reference to `System.Configuration` assembly to the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare various connections string in App.config and use use:

```
var conString =System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"];
string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM Table;"), con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And declare a connection string in App.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows form application there is Application config file in that you can add connection string and you can call that file to all page of that application.

You can right click to solution explorer and then add new Item and add App.Config file and in that there is tag for connection string same as in web application.

Answer (score 0):

`App.config` is what you are looking for.
[How to add configurations to windows forms](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/how-to-add-a-configuration-file-to-your-windows-forms-application/).

Also use [Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) to get your configurations.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any configuration file add below code in  your connection string

```
static string ConStr = "Data Source=DataSourceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
```

Comment: And what if end user want to give its own connection string? You will ship a code to him?

Answer (score 0):

place this code before namespace

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Add reference to System.Configuration assembly to the project.
Then use below code in c# form page

```
var conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"];
string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
```

Your app.config connectionstring should be like this.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CONSTRING" connectionString="Data Source=MONAIT-PC;Initial Catalog=CMS;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using connection two ways: 1. Sql Server Authentication
                              2. Windows Authentication

***{Sql Server Authentication}***

```
<connection string>
<add name="somename" connectionstring="database=databasename;data source=servername;uid=somename;pwd=somename(or)numbers">
</connection string>
```

***{Windows Server Authentication}***

```
<connection string>
<add name="somename" connectionstring="database=databasename;data source=servername; integrated security = true">
</connection string>
```